# Multiline UILabel not working in UITableViewCell?

Tags: uitableview, ios7, uilabel, multiline

I'm trying to use a multiline `UILabel` inside my custom `UITableViewCell`. Unfortunately the frame of the label is not correct, so therefore it's only showing one single line.

I've also set the numberOfLines and lineBreakMode properties.

```
cell.bodyLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
cell.bodyLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;
```

I'm also calculating the correct height of the cell, in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.

Set up in Storyboard and custom class: http://imgur.com/Dt35nIS

Settings of label in Storyboard: http://imgur.com/ZHKv8yt, https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MGVJ.jpg

**EDIT**

It turned out that the issue has something to do with Auto Layout, I added some constraints, now most of the cells are fine, but there are still a fews, where some Labels collapses with others. What do I need to check in this cases?

Comment: You have to set the height of the label as well. Or you use Auto Layout.

Comment: @dasdom where do you suggest to set the height of the label?

Comment: If you have a custom subclass of UITableViewCell, you could do it in `layoutSubviews`. Or you could do it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: Have you got any solution for this ? I too have a similar problem.